# Ruby on Rails: How to delete unused tags with acts-as-taggable-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I've followed the instructions at https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/wiki, and in config/initializers/acts_as_taggable_on.rb i've put

```
ActsAsTaggableOn.remove_unused_tags = true
```

However it didn't work. I've also tried the following similar to other gems:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn.setup do |config|
  config.remove_unused_tags = true
end
```

It didn't work either. Maybe it needs a module included?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my mistake. I tought it would delete all existing tags where taggings_count is 0. It deletes them upon removal from relationship.

Answer (score 5):

I have a rake task.

```
# lib/tasks/tag_cleaner.rake
# run using 'RAILS_ENV=development rake tag_cleaner:delete_unused'

namespace :tag_cleaner do
  desc "delete unused tags"
  task :delete_unused => :environment do
    ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.joins(
      "LEFT JOIN taggings on taggings.tag_id = tags.id").where("taggings.id is null").delete_all
  end

end
```

I use it when I need it.

OR

```
# lib/tasks/tag_cleaner.rake
# run using 'RAILS_ENV=development rake tag_cleaner:delete_unused'

namespace :tag_cleaner do
  desc "delete unused tags"
  task :delete_unused => :environment do
    ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.joins(
      "LEFT JOIN taggings on taggings.tag_id = tags.id").where("taggings.id is null").delete_all
    ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.joins(
      "LEFT JOIN tags on tags.id = taggings.tag_id").where("tags.id is null").delete_all
  end
end
```

If you need to go both ways. Ie You are playing around like I did and had delete some from tags and some from taggings and need to cleanse both sides.